# Titan could not instantiate implementation: CassandraThriftStoreManager

Tags: titan

> ./gremlin.sh
>
> gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("../conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties")

Then error occurred:

> Could not instantiate implementation:
>
> com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
>       Display stack trace? [yN]
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
>   implementation:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
>     at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
>     at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:144)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
>     ... 45 more Caused by:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException:
>   Temporary failure in storage backend  at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:208)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:186)
>     ... 50 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)    at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:88)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:52)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:21)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:205)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed
>   out   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)    ... 57
>   more

My Cassandra cluster and Elasticsearch cluster are ok. Thrift is enabled, and necessary port is open too.

Any help?

Comment: The root cause is` Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`. This means that you have a network or service issue of some sorts. Is Cassandra listening for thrift clients at all? In recent C* versions thrift is disabled by default.